# Element is disappearing from HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a website where I can add questions, I can add many questions and many options to every question.

My problem is that when I try to add a 2nd option to any question, the whole webpage refreshes and all my elements are disappearing.

I have no idea why, I have tried debugging and the option is being created correctly and successfully and just after it exits the method it just disappears.

If anyone knows what the problem may be or has seen something similar I would appreciate the help.

My code is:

```js
const questionnaire = document.getElementById('questionaire');

var optionsCounter = 0, optionsVector = [], questionsArray = [], optionsQN = 0;

questionnaire.onclick = ev => {
    if (ev.target.tagName === "BUTTON") {
        switch (ev.target.className) {
            case "remove-qu":
                switch (ev.target.parentNode.className) {
                    case "opQuestion":
                        optionsQN--;
                        document.getElementById('numberOfOptionsQuestions').innerHTML = "Option Questions = " + optionsQN;
                        break;
                }
                ev.target.parentNode.remove();
                break;
            case "add-li":
                newOption(ev.target.closest(".opQuestion").querySelector('ul'), true)
                break;
        }
    }
    else {
        switch (ev.target.className) {
            case "remove-li":
                optionsCounter--;
                optionsVector.pop(ev.target);
                ev.target.parentNode.remove();
                break;
            case "save-li":
                saveEdits(ev.target);
                break;
        }
    }
}

function saveEdits(caller) {
    var callerType = caller.className;
    switch (callerType) {
        case "save-li":
            var editElem = caller.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.innerHTML;
            var numberOfSubquestion = caller.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.id;
            var id = numberOfSubquestion.substr(5, (numberOfSubquestion.length - 1)); // Gets the first part
            var questionNumber = id[0];
            var optionNumber = id[1];
            document.getElementById("question" + questionNumber).childNodes[1].childNodes[optionNumber].childNodes[0].innerHTML = editElem;
            break;
    }
}

function newOpQuestion(questionNumber) {
    optionsQN++;
    document.getElementById('numberOfOptionsQuestions').innerHTML = "Option Questions = " + optionsQN;
    // Create: questionDiv -> nameDiv, ul 
    var question = document.createElement('div');
    var nameDiv = document.createElement('div');
    var removeButton = document.createElement('button');
    var saveButton = document.createElement('button');
    var unorderedList = document.createElement('ul');
    var addOptionButton = document.createElement('button');
    // Create: div id's
    var questionId = "question" + "" + questionNumber;
    var nameDivId = "label" + "" + questionNumber;
    var removeButtonId = "removeButton" + "" + questionNumber;
    var saveButtonId = "saveButton" + "" + questionNumber;
    var addOptionButtonId = "addOptionButton" + "" + questionNumber;
    question.id = questionId;
    nameDiv.id = nameDivId;
    removeButton.id = removeButtonId;
    saveButton.id = saveButtonId;
    addOptionButton.id = addOptionButtonId;
    removeButton.className = "remove-qu";
    saveButton.className = "save-qu";
    nameDiv.className = "questionName";
    question.className = "opQuestion";
    addOptionButton.className = "add-li";
    nameDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Your Question'));
    removeButton.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Remove Question'));
    saveButton.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Save Question'));
    addOptionButton.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Add Option'));
    question.append(nameDiv);
    question.append(removeButton);
    question.append(saveButton);

    question.append(unorderedList)    // Add optionDiv as child of li
    question.append(addOptionButton);
    questionnaire.append(question);
    newOption(unorderedList);
}

function newOption(q) {
        optionsCounter++;
        optionsVector.push(q);
        // Create: li -> span(label), input(checkbox), span(remove-li), span(save-li)
        var option = document.createElement('li');
        var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
        var label = document.createElement('span');
        var removeButton = document.createElement('span');
        var saveButton = document.createElement('span');
        // createId for all
        var optionId = "option" + "" + (optionsQN - 1) + (optionsCounter - 1);
        var checkBoxId = "checkbox" + "" + (optionsQN - 1) + (optionsCounter - 1);
        var labelId = "label" + "" + (optionsQN - 1) + (optionsCounter - 1);
        var removeButtonId = "remove-li" + "" + (optionsQN - 1) + (optionsCounter - 1);
        var saveButtonId = "save-li" + "" + (optionsQN - 1) + (optionsCounter - 1);
        // set id's for all
        checkbox.type = "checkbox";
        label.id = labelId;
        label.contentEditable = "true";
        option.id = optionId;
        checkbox.id = checkBoxId;
        removeButton.id = removeButtonId;
        saveButton.id = saveButtonId;
        // set class names for all
        option.className = "optionName";
        removeButton.className = "remove-li";
        saveButton.className = "save-li";

        checkBoxId.htmlFor = option;
        label.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Option'));
        saveButton.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Save Option'));
        removeButton.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Remove Option'));
        option.appendChild(label); //add `label` to `li`
        option.appendChild(checkbox); //add `checkbox` to `li`
        option.appendChild(removeButton);
        option.appendChild(saveButton);
        q.appendChild(option)
}

document.getElementById("addOpQuButton").onclick = function () { newOpQuestion(optionsQN); };
```

```css
 body {
    background-color: #1D2228;
}

#myText {
    color:white;
    margin: 20px;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
}

.opQuestion {
    border: 3px solid white;
    border-radius: 25px;
    color:white;
    margin: 30px 200px 20px 200px;
    text-align: center;
}

#addOpQuButton {
    font-size: 15px;  
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    background-color: #FB8122;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 25px;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}


.questionName {
    font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: italic;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.opQuestion ul li {
    display: block;
}

.optionName{
    font-size: 21px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-style: oblique;
}


.remove-li, .save-li {
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    background-color:#FB8122;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 25px;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.remove-qu, .save-qu {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    background-color: #FB8122;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 25px;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.add-li{
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    background-color: lightseagreen;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 25px;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
    
     <h1 id="myText" contenteditable="true">Survey Name</h1>
  <div id="buttons">
  <button type="button" id="addOpQuButton">Options</button>
  </div>

  <form>
    <div id="questionaire"></div>
  </form>
  <p class="counters" id="numberOfOptionsQuestions"></p>
```

Comment: Have you tried preventDefault() ?

Comment: Where should I put the ```preventDefault()```? I mean I want the option to be added when I press the button, I just don't want it to disappear and I don't know what is causing this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you click a `<button>` when inside a `<form>` element then the form will submit. See this example:

```js
document.forms[0].addEventListener('submit', e => alert('get submitted!'));
```

```html
<form>
<button>click me</button>
</form>
```

So if you want to stop that from happening, you can either change from `<button>` to `<input type="button">`:

```js
document.forms[0].addEventListener('submit', e => alert('get submitted!'));
```

```html
<form>
<input type="button" value="click me">
</form>
```

or you can add `e.preventDefault();` to the `onclick` handler for the button.

```js
document.forms[0].addEventListener('submit', e => alert('get submitted!'));
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].addEventListener('click', e => e.preventDefault());
```

```html
<form>
<button>click me</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I tried changing the type from button to input and it worked